# Bit bucket source control for SSMS, team explorer: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: version-control, ssms

I followed these steps to get source control into SSMS
https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/11/21/source-control-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/

I have created a solution and are able to work on it.

But when syncing the repositry via team explorer inside of SSMS I get the following error:

Inner Exception:
    The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

My current workaround is to sync outside of SMMS, but I would ike to do it from SMMS itself.

What i've tried:

Added regkeys to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319

SchUseStrongCrypto
SystemDefaultTlsVersions

Should they be added in an other place?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you ever got this solved but I was able to get it working by following the instructions on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Find the section "Configuring security via the Windows Registry" There is a .reg file you can create and import and, for me, it fixed the TLS issue for SSMS 2016.

I haven't tested this with version 17 but it should work there as well but from what I have heard, source control doesn't work with version 18 at all.